# How can I actually capture things between curly braces in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to capture everything between curly brackets. So if I have the string:

{this} {is a} blah {test}

should return [this, is a, test].

My code looks like this:

```
var myString = "{this} {is a} blah {test}";
var parts = (/{([^{}]+)}/g).exec(myString);

//   parts = [{this}, {is a}, {test}]  


var parts = (/{([^{}]+)}/g).exec(myString);
//   parts = [{this}, this]
```

Any ideas/help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're over-egging the pudding:

```
var rex = /\{([^}]+)\}/g;
var str = "{this} {is a} blah {test}";
var m;
for (m = rex.exec(str); m; m = rex.exec(str)) {
    console.log(m[1]);
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ahikaz/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ahikaz/1/edit)

Answer (score -2):

```
var parts = myString.match(/{[^}]+/g).map(function (s) { return s.slice(1); });
```

Comment: They don't change anything. The problem is that you cannot get the capturing group of all matches in a single call in JavaScript.

Comment: Updated it. It is possible with a single line.

Comment: @BrianCray: Nope, still doesn't work. Did you bother to try it with the sample input? I mean, one paste into the console...

Comment: @BrianCray works for the first two and then matches `blah {test`.

Comment: Updated it using Array.map to remove the {, it at least prevents to regex exec in a loop proposed above.

Comment: @BrianCray however, the loop is the standard practice in JS (as far as I know) and I find the `map` solution more obfuscating than anything else. Plus, this approach only works in this case where the capture's only purpose is to cut off a character from the beginning and the end of the string. It is in no way generalizable to a different problem where multiple captures need to be retrieved and hence barely educational. (Only my 2 cents though)

Comment: Whether you use traditional fors or not is a matter of preference, but the performance is different at least on my test: http://jsperf.com/testing-regex